Не получается запарсить json-запрос удаленного сервера на PHP
Удаленный сервер обращается к моему с следующим запросом:
sendNotificationAsync(): url=****************/getReq.php, request.object={
  "id" : "po-2e0b0050-0003-5000-a000-08b0474395ad",
  "amount" : {
    "value" : "65.00",
    "currency" : "RUB"
  },
  "status" : "succeeded",
  "payout_destination" : {
    "type" : "bank_card",
    "card" : {
      "first6" : "*******",
      "last4" : "****",
      "card_type" : "Visa",
      "issuer_country" : "RU",
      "issuer_name" : "Alfa-Bank"
    }
  },
  "description" : "SAFE_DEAL",
  "created_at" : "2024-06-24T03:48:33.208Z",
  "deal" : {
    "id" : "****************"
  },
  "metadata" : {
    "order_id" : "12120697"
  },
  "test" : false
}, headers=[Signature: v1 2e0b006a 1 MGQCMBM/d5VCjHLDz53bK7RAr93sm3G6ibYuw8C1tJANZKV8nOJx8mym5IjxiffdmiyxpgIwbGpvt/MdgHtrhArKscnmg//PyDF1xppgvrIx1FlK8tFHLJd1cB502FErxzP3hphJ, Content-Type: application/json, User-Agent: AHC/2.1, Accept: */*]

Ответ, который получает сервер:
END http request: method=POST, url=*********/getReq.php, status=200, time.ms=9

Исходя из того, что сервер отправляет application/json, пытаюсь спарсить данные из запроса на своей стороне:
$source = file_get_contents('php://input');
$requestBody = json_decode($source, true);
// Пробовал по разному, т.к. видел разные примеры.
file_put_contents("getReq1.txt", $requestBody["id"]." ".$requestBody["deal"]["id"]." ".$requestBody["status"]."1");
file_put_contents("getReq2.txt", $requestBody->id." ".$requestBody->deal->id." ".$requestBody->status." 1");

В файл записывается только " 1", приписываемая к концу строки, соответственно, к файлу обращение происходит, но данные не получается спарсить.
Пробовал еще вариант просто получить $_POST запрос, но тоже неудачно:
$requestBody = json_decode($_POST, true);
file_put_contents("getReq1.txt", $requestBody->id." ".$requestBody->deal->id." ".$requestBody->status." 1");
file_put_contents("getReq2.txt", $_POST["id"]." ".$_POST["deal"]["id"]." ".$_POST["amount"]["value"]." ".$_POST["status"]."1");

Что делаю со своей стороны не так?

идея записать в файл содержимое $source в голову не приходила?

Да, действительно, идея хорошая, помогло. Неправильно обращался.

Данная проблема показала важность использования отладки для решения возникающих проблем.
Главной составляющей отладки является проверка реально полученных данных на соответствие ожиданиям. Записав полученный JSON в файл, удалось выяснить, что данные имеют другую структуру. После указания правильных ключей в распакованном массиве, удалось получить нужные значения.

похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите
